# Menu display issue on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a website for a customer who insists on an "old style" website, i.e. fixed everything and not Responsive.

This site has done well over the years, but right now I'm having an issue with the display of the menu in Safari. It looks great in all browsers except Safari. On Safari it cuts off some of the menu bar (color behind menu).

URL: http://fifthaveinternetgarage.com/

Safari:

[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hieRM.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the HTML and CSS for the menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your `#nav` and `#nav a` both have `background-color: #a83141;`. On Safari, your menu items are likely larger than your menu itself, causing a larger menu on most of it except the edges. I'd recommend setting `background-color: transparent;` on your `#nav a`.